If a Jew cuts an onion with a cold milchig knife, May they cook or eat it with meat
According to Halacha, after cutting an onion with a cold milchig knife, may it be cooked or eaten with meat? Does the taste (טעם) transfer to the onion even if it’s cold?

See this article https://www.star-k.org/articles/kashrus-kurrents/597/sharp-awareness-in-the-kitchen/#:~:text=The%20Magen%20Avraham23%20rules,not%20be%20eaten%20with%20dairy.

What if a non-Jew does the cutting?

@Kirk I guess this is good of a time as any... out of curiosity (no disrespect intended), why do you start off many (perhaps most?) of your questions asking some variation of "if a Jew/may a Jew/do Jews" etc.? I think we generally take it for granted around here that unless otherwise stated, the default context is a Jew/Jews.

right... but if you were to have written: "if an onion is cut with a cold milchig knife, may the onion be cooked or eaten with meat?" I don't think most of us would have thought that you weren't asking about a Jewish/halakhic context. I'm not really seeing anything achieved with the additional verbiage... again, just trying to understand

A good tip to remember the laws of duchka d’sakinah b'davar harif (a knife pressed into a sharp food) is that it "upgrades" (so to speak) the status of the knife from eino ben yomo to ben yomo and from cold to hot. In other words, a cold knife not used for 24 hours is considered as if it was hot and used within 24 hours.
As such, in the case of your question, the onion is treated as if it had absorbed the taste of milk, becomes dairy (assuming it is smaller than 60 times the volume of the knife), and cannot be cooked or eaten together with meat.
For more see SA YD 96 with commentaries as well as this Star-K article.

According to the mechaber charif is limited to chiltas

This assumes you are unable to taste the onion to see if it tastes dairy-y.
